# Some classes aren't being recognized in managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, beta-managed-package

I have a managed package which I installed on different orgs with no problems. Recently I added 2 new classes and all hell broke loose. I packaged it fine, compiled fine, passed all the unit tests just fine. When I tried to install it on a sandbox it gave errors about not recognizing some vars from a class that I know(checked) is included. I then removed the 2 new classes, repackaged it and it was the same. 
I should mention that all the other files are Managed-released but the package is currently beta. The 2 new files I added are also beta (blue instead of green) but the errors are not about the new classes.

I made a case to SF but they said they can't help me because it's dev related so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on the "errors about not recognizing some vars from a class that I know(checked) is included" part of the question. What was the exact error message. Was it in classes outside the managed package?

Comment: It's not recognizing a boolean var from one of the classes that is included in the package. Then several errors down it says it doesn't know who that same class is. Then it says it's not recognizing another class that was in the package from the begining. When I check the components of the package they are all there and the vars are accessible and the classes that need to be global, are. I think it shouldn't pass the compiling or unit test phase if that was the case.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the class and variable names are. There isn't any overlap in the naming or reserved keywords being used?

Comment: The class that's causing problems has also been there since the creation of the package (long ago) and it was all good since now. It's an util type of class that contains some static methods and vars that are used in all other classes. It's name is also 'Util'.